# NO WIFI ADAPTER, Ubuntu 19.10, Lenovo S340

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Lenovo S340, Ubuntu 19.10.

I can't properly identify the Network Card. `lspci` outputs `Intel Corporation Device 02f0`.

I've tried Ubuntu 18.04 before with no luck.

I cannot believe this does not work out of the box. I've tried several drivers, all to no avail.

While installing, I was able to connect to my wifi and download the packages.

After installed, ubuntu no longer finds a Wifi Adapter.

`iwconfig` ouput is plainly: `lo      no wireless extensions`

I don't know what to do anymore. I can't plug an Ethernet Cable in because there no Ethernet port, so... what can I do???

Comment: Could that be "InteL Corporation Device" ?  If so, anything from the iwlwifi module in your logs?

Comment: You're correct, I mispelled Intel. What logs are you talking abou?

Comment: /var/log/messages would be start.  Anything from the iwlwifi driver?